# Calling method from another class - Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am trying something like below and I am getting red lines under any formDesign commands such as messageBox, dataGridView etc.

I want to put the body of the methods in a seperate .cs page for neatness and call them from mainForm.cs

Is this the wrong way to call methods

```
mainForm.cs

namespace App{
      public partial class mainForm : Form{
             private void saveCSVbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
                className.method();
             }
      }
}
```

```
class.cs

namespace App{
      class className{
              private void method(){MessageBox.Show("No Record To Export", "Info");}
      }
}
```

Comment: As method() is private you cant call it from outside, so yes, it's the wrong way, also if you want to call it thay way you need it to be static

Comment: The private property is preventing you from calling the method from a different class.  You can remove private.

Comment: the point of the `private`-keyword is to hold things private to the class that method is in. Maybe you should make that method `internal` or even `public`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers for further info.

Comment: Ah ok Thank you. I still have the red lines on `dataGridView` and `textBoxName` though. do they have to be declared in the class or passed to the method as parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want put some code in a function, you should declare the function like

```
public static class MyClass{
      public static void MyMethod(){...}
}
```

If you only need the method from within the same project you can replace `public` with `internal`.

A static method is appropriate if the method only depends on the given parameters, if it needs to maintain a state you need to remove the `static`, create an object of the class in your form, and use that object to call the method.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, I have done this but I still get red lines when I try to use dataGridView1 or textBox1 in the class.cs (same project different .cs file)

Comment: @elaine fields are only directly accessible in the declaring class. My guess is that you want to declare your method inside your main form class. The alternative would be to pass these fields as method parameters to your static method. There is also partial classes, but I would not recommend that if you are just getting started.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate different layers of an app, I suggest you use a design pattern like MVVM. This way you would have classes that does the functionality of the app and other classes work with database and so on.